# Table Switcher Hiding Tables

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, css-tables

I'm having trouble making it so if I click a button, one table becomes hidden and another is shown.

Here is a link to the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LpLhP/30/)

Here are the main bits of code:

```
<div id="container">    
    <table id="1" div id="table3">
        <div class="table_2col">
            <div class="caption">
                <ul>

            </div><!--/ column 3-->    
            <div class="clear"></div>   
        </div><!--/. table_3col-->

        <div class="table_4col">
            <div class="caption">
```

I'm using table id ="1" for the first table and table id="2" for the second, but doing this seems to take away the css style.

Css:

```
a.button{    
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover;
}
a.button:nth-child(1){
     background-color: #FA202B;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    var tables = $("table");
    //Grabs all the tables
    tables.hide().first().show();
    //Hides all the tables except first
    $("a.button").on("click", function () {
        //Adds eventListner to buttons
        tables.hide();
        //Hides all the tables
        var tableTarget = $(this).data("table");
        //Gets data# of button
        $("table#" + tableTarget).show();
        //Shows the table with an id equal to data attr of the button
    })
})();
```

Comment: Dude that fiddle is awful and **really long**...no one is going to read through that whole thing. Just post the important pieces. Plus, I don't see any tables, and the image/css/js links are relative, which are not going to work on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set all tables to `display:none;` and then use [jQuery Toggle Class](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to add an overriding "visible" class to the current table.